# how add auth session to param array public $belongsTo Model

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I want to add `$this->Auth->user('id')` to Model User

```
 public $belongsTo = array('Role' => array('conditions' => array('User.id' =>$this->Auth->user('id') )));
```

This code has error!.I don't know how to use Auth here.

Comment: You should use debug function in cake and read up on creating and destroying associations on the fly in cake docs.

Answer (score -1):

Write at the top of model below line

```
App::uses('Component', 'Auth');
```

and then use `Auth` session like this

```
authComponent::user("id")
```

An alternative to this is

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
$Session = new CakeSession();
$user = $Session->read('Auth.User');
```

Now `$user` have all the data that `$this->Auth->user` have

**Update**
Ok, Just write `App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');` in your model
and use `CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id')` as

```
public $belongsTo = array(
  'Role' => array(
      'conditions' => array(
          'User.id' => CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id') 
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: you are right.but i want $user use in conditions $belongsTo.but i have erore PHP!.

Comment: @MEHDIFATHI, please check the Update